# how to modify existing ocmod.xml file without reinstalling new file on Opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart, ocmod

I have a simple ocmod.xml for my opencart 2.3 application.
I've uploaded the changes but now I need to modify it.
Instead of reinstalling the new version, how can I quickly modify it and refresh modification during development?
Where is the file located?

Comment: You can modify corresponding file which is placed in storage/modification corresponding folder. this will be more faster. after you reach desired result you can modify your ocmod xml file, upload it and refresh modifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded the file via the admin end then it will be stored in your MySQL database. Under modifications table in the database and the xml row in the table you will see it. If you edit it there then clear and refresh the modifications you will see the changes.

You can also do it we try a new miss called an ocmod manager. This all is you to edit from admin [for opencart 2x](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22318&filter_rating=3&page=7) or for [opencart 3x](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=33725&filter_member=magicmike)

Comment: No you can't, there is not the option to edit the code of the OCMOD in the admin.

Comment: You can in the MySQL database. Don't turn mark an answer if you don't know anything. The OC mod is stored. It is stored in the database called (OC prefix)_modification then in the xml column.